# JSON data partially cannot be changed

Tags: javascript, json

I'm stuck with this small piece of code that isn't supposed to be complicated, this small piece of JSON data cannot be changed unlike everything else.

Original JSON data:
**apptData.push({
        'service': serviceName,
        'duration': rawDuration,
        'tech' : selectedTech
    })**

I wanted to consolidate it into: **finalApptData** in **findTimeSlots()**

The small piece of data I want to change is: **finalApptDatap[j].service** to hold more info but it would not be changed when viewed using console.log()

I use **console.log(finalApptData);** at the end of everything to check.

```
var apptData = [];
function addApptData(serviceName, rawDuration, selectedTech){
    apptData.push({
        'service': serviceName,
        'duration': rawDuration,
        'tech' : selectedTech
    })
}
function reduceApptData(index){
    apptData.splice(index, 1);
}
function findTimeSlots(dateStr){
    var finalApptData = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < apptData.length; i++){
        var duplicated = false;
        for(var j = 0; j < finalApptData.length; j++){
            if(finalApptData[j].tech == apptData[i].tech){

//All those line changing finalApptData[j].service are from multiple attempts. 
// I must have done something wrong but I'm not sure where.

                    **finalApptData[j].service = "changed";
                    finalApptData[j].service.push("apptData[i].service");
                    finalApptData[j].service.push(apptData[i].service);
                    finalApptData[j].service += apptData[i].service;
                    finalApptData[j].service += ", "+apptData[i].service;**

                finalApptData[j].duration += apptData[i].duration;
                duplicated = true;
            }
        }
        if(!duplicated){
            finalApptData.push(apptData[i]);
        }
    }
    console.log(finalApptData);
    $.post('./getTimeSlots.php', {'date': dateStr}, function(response){
        console.log("Response: "+response);
    });
}
```

Comment: *What* "small piece of JSON data" can't be changed? How do you know? Are errors reported? Does *anything* happen?

Comment: All those line changing finalApptData[j].service are from multiple attempts. I must have done something wrong but I'm not sure where.

Comment: we have no idea what your json looks like

Comment: Your `console.log()` statement is **before** the statements that attempt to change the value.

Comment: @Pointy It was not the one I used to check if it's changed. I use the 2nd one that console.log(finalApptData); outside the loop, I just put it there to see if it works. It does show the data, but any attempt to change after it would not work.

Comment: @imvain2 sorry, I initialized the var ApptData = []; outside and on the top of the .js file.

Comment: The problem is apptData is an object not array, so appending to the object like an array won't work.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is apptData is an object not array, so appending to the object like an array won't work. Instead I created an array and pushed to that instead.

```js
var apptData = [];
function addApptData(serviceName, rawDuration, selectedTech){
    apptData.push({
        'service': serviceName,
        'duration': rawDuration,
        'tech' : selectedTech
    })
}
function reduceApptData(index){
    apptData.splice(index, 1);
}
function findTimeSlots(dateStr){
    var finalApptData = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < apptData.length; i++){
        var duplicated = false;
        for(var j = 0; j < finalApptData.length; j++){
            if(finalApptData[j].tech == apptData[i].tech){
                let obj = [apptData[i].service];
                obj.push(finalApptData[j].service);
                finalApptData[j].service = obj;
                finalApptData[j].duration += apptData[i].duration;
                duplicated = true;
            }
        }
        if(!duplicated){
            finalApptData.push(apptData[i]);
        }
    }
    console.log(finalApptData);
}

addApptData("A", 1, "X");
addApptData("V", 2, "C");
addApptData("V3", 32, "C");
addApptData("Va3", 322, "AxC");

findTimeSlots("");
```

Comment: When I try that code with addApptData("A", 1, "X");
addApptData("V", 2, "AC");
addApptData("V3", 32, "AC");
addApptData("Va3", 322, "AxC"); I get error that push is not a function.